# configure gnu.io.rxtx.properties android

Tags: java, android, ioexception

When I try to run a new, blank android project in the latest eclipse SDK a window pops up that says "configure gnu.io.rxtx.properties". (It's the one with 128 check boxes representing 128 serial ports)

When I select some ports and click save, an IOException appears in the console window and nothing else happens.

The project will not run. The window will not go away. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Silly mistake, for some reason 'configure' was set to run and not my project.
Right-click, run as, android. solved.